# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a Block "callback"

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

ClassA.h stuff

```
typedef void (^ ValidatorBlock)(BOOL);
...
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
    ValidatorBlock validatorBlock;
}
...
- (void)setValidatorBlock:(ValidatorBlock)block;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) ValidatorBlock validatorBlock;
```

ClassA->setValidatorBlock

```
- (void)setValidatorBlock:(ValidatorBlock)block {
    validatorBlock = [block copy];
}
```

ClassA->validateForm

```
- (void)validateForm {
    validatorBlock(NO);
}
```

ClassA->textFieldDidEndEditing

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self validateForm];
}
```

ClassB->viewDidLoad - where the *magic* happens

```
void (^block)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL is_valid) {
    // works fine when passed NO, always crashes when passed YES with EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    NSLog(@"block: %@", is_valid);
};

ClassA *classA = [[ClassA alloc] init];
[classA setValidatorBlock:block];
```

I skimmed a number of *google articles* and my implementations with `copy` still gave me the same issue. Any ideas?

** ***after answer*** **

@vikingosegundo shared a great link on [String Specifier Formats](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)

Comment: +1 for adding useful information for future readers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BOOL` is not an object. use `@"%d"` instead for logging

or

```
void (^block)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL is_valid) {

    if (is_valid) NSLog(@"YES", nil);
    else NSLog(@"NO", nil);

};
```

yet another way with [Ternary Operator](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions#The_Ternary_Operator):

```
NSLog(is_valid ? @"Yes" : @"No");
```

Comment: [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFStrings/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1)